# Use a variable as a nth selector?

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to select all elements with class .formRow greater than a defined variable (x). How do I call the variable within the tag?

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
  var x = 1;
  $('.formRow:nth('x') ~ .formRow').toggleClass('subEdit');

});
```

Comment: `$('.formRow:nth('+x+') ~ .formRow')`

Comment: `:nth` pseudo selector ???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be `nth-child()`.
Also, you need to use `+` to combinate a string with a variable:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var x = 1;
  $('.formRow:nth-child('+x+') ~ .formRow').toggleClass('subEdit');
});
```

Please note that this isn't a class selector. So, if `x=3`, it will not select the third `.formRow`. It will select the third child that also has the `.formRow` class! If that is what you are looking for, then use

```
$('.formRow').eq(x)
```

Comment: Ah, I'll try use .eq instead then, thanks a lot. Sorry I'm a jQuery newbie

Comment: No problem. Look at the jQuery website, you'll find lots of info's there! For example about [`eq()`](https://api.jquery.com/eq/)

Answer (score 0):

Use :

```
$('.formRow:gt('+x+')').toggleClass('subEdit');
```

where 'x' is the 0 based index.

Read : https://api.jquery.com/gt-selector/

```js
var x = 3; // from 0 to 3 indices. 
$('.myDiv:gt('+x+')').toggleClass('color'); // gt, i.e. greater than x (0 based)
```

```css
.color {
  border: 2px red solid;
}

div{
  border: 2px green solid;
  display:inline-block;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="myDiv"></div>
<div class="myDiv"></div>
<div class="myDiv"></div>
<div class="myDiv"></div>
<div class="myDiv"></div>
<div class="myDiv"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var x = 2;
    $('.formRow:nth(' + x + ') ~ .formRow').toggleClass('subEdit');
});
```

Just need to add the concatenation + to use the variabe.